# When i try to create intent using python in api.ai, it cannot be created

Tags: python, python-3.x

when i try to create intent in api.ai using python SDK i am unable to create it.
No Errors were shown in the coding.

---

```
agent.intents.create(
     'name',
     {'templates': [
         "Who am I?"
     ]}
)
```

Comment: How do you determine that it failed?

Comment: no intent was created in api.ai